# how to Call Restful web service using javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have Restful webservice return data in xml style
I but url in browser like :

```html
http://localhost:3085/BasicService.svc/sess_details?subject = 999
```

it gaves me

```html
<subjectDetails xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CA_WCF" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CommitteeId>121</CommitteeId>
<IsCommittee>true</IsCommittee>
<Name>new employees</Name>
<Number>six</Number>
<subjectDate>10/02/1434</subjectDate>
<subjectId>999</subjectId>
<Status>5</Status>
<UserId>0</UserId>
</subjectDetails>
```

How to call webservice and store result ( this xml data ) in  javascript variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert the returned XML to JSON which you can store in a variable.

http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/

Comment: The problem is how to get that data from webservice use javascript?

Comment: You can use Jquery Ajax call as follows :$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3085/BasicService.svc/sess_details?subject=999",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml(response)
   });